# Worldwide zip/postal search on site

Tags: web-development

I need people to be able to search from a *worldwide* database of businesses on my site. Consumers will enter their zip/postal code, and then a list of businesses within 250 miles/km must show in search results. So far I have successfully finished for USA, because I could find the all the zips & coordinates for USA, but can't find for the rest of the world? Does anyone know where I can find this information? Thanks

Comment: Thank You. I didn't even realize there was an option for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello jeff**,

I will answer your question, although this kind of information is very easy to come by. Next time try a search engine first.

### Remarks

1. Most of the registers below require registration and payment before you get access to any data.
2. These registers contain basic information such as Name, Category and address. You will have to combine this information with geographical data, to get coordinates and distances to other business entities. I leave it up to you and your query skills, to find more information about the available options.
3. As a challenge to you, and as a punishment for your laziness, I have filtered out any links and other information that might have made the task a bit easier for you. It took me approximately one minute to retrieve the data from Internet, and a bit more to clean it up. Due to *space limitations*, I *had* to contract the data somewhat.

The available business registers are as follows.

### Europe

The European Business Register: Austria,  Belgium,  Germany,  Estonia,  Spain,  Ireland,  Italy,  Greece,  Latvia,  Norway,  France,  Finland,  Denmark,  Sweden,  Jersey,  United Kingdom,  Netherlands,  Ukraine,  Serbia,  Slovenia,  Macedonia,  Portugal,  and Luxembourg.

### The rest of the world - the US

Anguilla, Anguilla Offshore, Argentina, Argentine Companies Office, Aruba, Aruba Financial Centre, Australia, Australian Securities and Investments Commission, Austria, Austrian Datakom, Belgium, Belgian Euro DB, Bermuda, Bermudian Registrar of Companies, Brazil, Brazilian DNRC, Brunei, Bruneian BSMENET, Canada, Alberta - Alberta Government Services, British Columbia - British Columbia Corporate Registry, Manitoba - Manitoba Companies Office, New Brunswick - New Brunswick Corporate Registry, Newfoundland and Labrador - Government of Newfoundland and Labrador - Canada, Nova Scotia - Service Nova Scotia - Registry of Joint Stock Companies, Ontario - Ontario, Prince Edward Island - Office of the Attorney General and Public Safety: Corporate/Business Names Registry, Quebec - Registraire des entreprises Quebec, Saskatchewan - Corporations Branch, Cambodia, Cambodian Ministry of Commerce, Colombia, Colombian Confecameras, Cook Islands, Financial Supervisory Commission - Cook Islands Registrar's Office, Croatia, Croatian Company Directory, Curaçao, Curacao Chamber of Commerce & Industry, Cyprus, Cypriot Department of Registrar of Companies, Department of the Registrar of Companies and Official Receiver, Czech republic, Czech business register search, Czech register of economic entities, Czech Registers of Economic Subjects, Denmark, Danish Companies Office, Estonia, Estonian Centre of Registers, Baltic Legal Estonia, Faroe Islands, Company Registration Authority, Fiji, Fiji Government, Finland, Finnish Trade Register, Finnish Companies Office, France, Registre du commerce et des sociétés, French Greffe du Tribunal de Commerce de Paris, French INPI, Germany, German Trade Register, German Handelsregister, Ghana, Ghanaian Ministry of Trade & Industry, Gibraltar, Gibraltar Government, Greece, Greek Athens Chamber of Commerce & Industry, Hong Kong, Hong Kong Companies Registry, Hungary, Hungarian Ministry of Justice-Companies Registration Office, Iceland, Statistics Iceland, India, Ministry of Corporate Affairs, Ireland, Companies Registration Office, Irish Companies Registration Office, Italy, Register of Companies, Italian InfoCamere, Japan, Japanese Companies Office, Latvia, Register of Enterprises, Baltic Legal, Liechtenstein, Liechtenstein FirstLink, Lithuania, Baltic Legal, Luxembourg, Luxembourg Registre de Commerce et des Societes, Malta, Registry of Companies, Maltese Registry of Companies, Malaysia, Malaysia Company Registration licensed company QADKAM, Malaysia Company Registration Agent, Suruhanjaya Syarikat Malaysia, Mauritius, The Mauritius Chamber of Commerce and Industry, Montenegro, Central Registry of the Commercial Court, Netherlands, Dutch Chamber of Commerce, Trade Register, New Zealand, Companies Office, Nigeria, Nigerian Corporate Affairs Commission, Niue, Companies Office of Niue, Pakistan, Pakistani Securities & Exchange Commission, Panama, Panamanian Public Registry, Philippines, Philippine Securities & Exchange Commission, Poland, Ministry of Justice, Russian Federation, State Register of companies , Samoa, Samoa International Finance Authority, Singapore, Singaporean Accounting & Corporate Regulating Authority, Slovakia, Companies Register of the Slovak Republic, Trade Register of the Slovak Republic, Slovenia, Slovenian Tradepoint, South Africa, South African Companies Office, Spain, Registro Mercantil Central, Association of Spanish Property & Commercial Registers, Sweden, Swedish Companies Registration Office, Switzerland, Swiss Companies Office, Tonga, Government of Tonga, Ukraine, State Committee, Ministry of Justice, National bank of Ukraine for banks, Derzhavny komitet finansovykh poslug for credit unions, United Kingdom, Companies House, United Kingdom Companies House, Isle of Man - Isle of Man Financial Supervision Commission, Jersey - Jersey Financial Services Commission, Northern Ireland - Northern Ireland Companies Registry, Vanuatu, Government of the Republic of Vanuatu, Zambia, Zambia Investment Centre.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding!

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is legal in any way and you should check t & c 's

but

When someone enters a post / zip code you don't know about you could query google maps to extract the lat and long of that code. Store the results and then do your search based on that, over time you would build up quite a database of entries. (oops did I just say that)

You should be aware though that post / zip codes often have copyright attached to them and you should pay a license to use them. The UK for example offer a service called PAF which is hugely expensive but in return for your fee you are kept upto date with changes within the country. You will be surprised how many there are within say 12 months (its many 1,000's) so maintaining a global database is a huge project.